# Border applied by CSS style not showing up consistently only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to apply a double border to a header element. The fiddle above works as expected in all browsers except for Chrome. In Chrome (using version 37.0.2062.120 on Windows 7 here), the bottom border in some cases is 2px away from the top border and in other cases is 1px away. I do not understand this inconsistency. Using the web inspector, I see some weird decimal heights for elements, so I assume it is some rounding error. Where are these decimal heights coming from?

Here's the fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/7qshmLbv/2/**

and here is the CSS style I'm using:

```
h2 {
    color: #023D62;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #7F7F7F;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2:before {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -4px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Could anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm an idiot. Turns out my browser was zoomed in on Chrome.